# Bind asp.net control's value to code behind function

Tags: asp.net

I have a hidden field that i want to bind to either a function on the page's code behind. I don't quite recall the exact syntax and i can't find the answer via Google. Is the code below correct? Thank.

```
print("<asp:HiddenField ID="dummy" Value='<%#Getdummy() %>' runat="server" />");
```

Comment: Is there a print function in asp.net? There are quotation marks inside the string with out escape sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've put looks pretty good ...

The two step process is ... add the hidden field to the markup

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# GetValue() %>'/>
```

Then create the specified method signature ...

```
protected string GetValue()
{
   return "something";
}
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: One thing I would like to add, DataBinding is not supported by MenuItem so this method can not be used to enable/disable a particular item in a menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the hidden field with runat=server, you could write code to assign value in the code behind (rather than in the markup).